Side-lobe reduction in ground penetrating radars
I'm working with ground-penetrating radar (GPR), which is a wideband radar capable of transmitting arbitrary waveforms from 110 MHz to 1 GHz.
We usually send a wide-band linear chirp signal (110 MHz to 1 GHz) and use pulse compression to generate our radargram. As you know, range side-lobes can mask weak targets in the presence of a strong target (in this case, the ground surface). Windowing can reduce side lobes; however, in our situation, since low frequencies penetrate the ground much better and are located at the edge of the spectrum, windowing is not very effective. While it reduces the side lobes of our strong scatterer (the ground), it also heavily attenuates the signal reflected from targets buried in the ground.
Is there any way to reduce the side lobes without attenuating the low frequencies (which are at the edge of the spectrum)?

Are you transmitting pulses where the bandwidth is 110 MHz to 1 GHz? Or are these your center frequencies with a smaller bandwidth around them? Also, are you concerned with range or Doppler sidelobes, or both?

Since you mention a spectrum, I'm guessing you are using dechirp-on-receive so the matched filter is an FFT? Or am I wrong? I'm not super familiar with GPR specifically.

I'm sending a wide-band signal from 110 MHz to 1 GHz to have resolution (at least for the surface) and good penetration (for low frequency). My goal is to detect different layers in the ground, therefore I'm concerned about range sidelobes.
No, I'm not dechirp my receive signal. I matched filter the received signal with the transmit signal (convolving the received signal and time reversed of original signal)
